# How to replace a substring from a variable?

Tags: bash, string

I am trying to remove characters from a string variable. It works for me with `sed` like this:

```
MYVAR=--23ho02123ware38384you443d34o3434ingtod38384day-%§*#sfrf
echo ${MYVAR} | sed -e 's/[a-z][a-z0-9\-]*//g'
```

and I get:

```
 --23%§*#
```

which is what I am looking for. The string should start with a letter and contain only letters, digits, and a dash (-).
Is there a way to achieve this with `bash` string replacement?

```
MYVAR=${MYVAR/[a-z][a-z0-9-]*/ }
```

I tried several combinations, but none of them work as I expected.

Comment: bash string replacement does NOT support regex! bash string replacement is doing globbing where *  equals .* in regex. check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd need to use the ksh extended glob operators (a subset of which is available in `bash` with `shopt -s extglob` and with `zsh` with `set -o kshglob`) to get the equivalent of regular expressions (though with a different syntax: `*(x)` for the equivalent of `x*` here):

```
shopt -s extglob # for bash
# set -o kshglob # for zsh
printf '%s\n' "${MYVAR//[[:alpha:]]*([[:alnum:]-])/}"
```

Or with `zsh` `extendedglob`s where the equivalent of regexp `*` is `#`:

```
set -o extendedglob
printf '%s\n' ${MYVAR//[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]-]#}
```

A few notes:

- `${var/pattern/replacement}` replaces only the first occurrence. Use `${var//pattern/replacement}` to replace every occurrence (like with the `g` flag in `sed`'s `s` command).
- you had made your replacement a space character. Use `${var//pattern/}` (or `${var//pattern}`) to replace with the empty string.
- [You don't want to use `echo` to output arbitrary strings](/q/65803)
- Except in `zsh`, [variable expansions in list contexts have to be quoted](/q/171346/)
- the behaviour would be different compared to your `sed` approach when the variable contains newline characters.
- `[a-z]` matches characters (collating elements in some tools) comprised between `a` and `z`, the list of which varies with the locale, the system and the tool (for instance `[a-z]` with `bash-4.3` in a `en_GB.UTF-8` locale on a GNU system matches `A`, `X`, `é`, `Ẃ`, but not `Z`). That generally includes the 26 lower case letters of the English alphabet but not necessarily. `[[:alpha:]]` includes characters (or collating elements) that are considered *alphabetical* (regardless of case) in your locale. If you only want to match the 26 English letters, either use `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` or fix the locale to `C` (`LC_ALL=C`) and use `[a-z]` or `[[:lower:]]` for lower case English letters only or `[a-zA-Z]`/`[[:alpha:]]` for any English letter.
- `[a-z0-9\-]` in `sed` does match the backslash character, use `[a-z0-9-]` instead (the `-` has to be first or last to be taken literally).

Comment: could also add that `//` is equivalent for `g` flag as opposed to `/` used by OP, and that the last space in OP's attempt will replace matched pattern with space

Comment: Thanks a lot Stéphane Chazelas, it works like a charm, even without the ksh extended glob operators `shopt -s extglob`. Best

Comment: CORRECTION: shopt extglob was already enabled on my machine, so I need it indeed! Thanks again

Comment: nice explanation! I saw the the space character in my replacement, which I already corrected. I am using en_US.UTF-8 locale on the system, but exporting de_DE.UTF-8 when running the script to be able to convert European letters to ASCII characters, since en_US.UTF-8 does not convert them correctly. New line characters are not a problem, since this string is a user login entered in bash prompt. This is a part of a huge script I wrote to create LDAP accounts in two different servers, and I am trying to force the script to accept only valid format login. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sundeep, good point. I've now incorporated those notes and a few more.