# how to mv files with a particular pattern to files with a particular pattern

Tags: linux, files, rename

Suppose I have file inside a directory as:

```
check_abc, check_bcd, check_cde
```

and I want to convert them to:

```
check1_abc, check1_bcd, check1_cde
```

How do I do that, as there could be 100's of file like this in one folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For your example, you could try a simple for loop like this:

```
for file in check*; do mv "$file" "${file/check/check1}"; done
```

- The `for file in check*;` part will iterate over all files that match `check*` and invoke the mv command.
- `${file/check/check1}` replaces the first instance of "check" with "check1".

So if one value of `$file` was "check_abc" the command that would be called would be: `mv check_abc check1_abc`;

Related:

- [How to replace a substring from a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318981/how-to-replace-a-substring-from-a-variable)

Comment: Hi Jeff/Stefan, Thanks for your help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 rename 's/check_/check1_/' check_*
```